# No generic method 'ThenBy'

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to add the `ThenById()` method which will be launched after a call to `OrderBy()` on `IOrderedQueryable`:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ThenById<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    var command = "ThenBy";
    var thenByProperty = "Id";
    var type = typeof(TEntity);

    if (type.GetProperty(thenByProperty) == null)
    {
        throw new MissingFieldException(nameof(thenByProperty));
    }

    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");

    var property = type.GetProperty(thenByProperty, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, property);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, param);

    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(IOrderedQueryable),
        command,
        new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

I receive the following error message:

> No generic method 'ThenBy' on type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but shouldn't you use an `System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable` as the `this` parameter of your extension method ?

Comment: `ThenBy` is an extension method on `System.Linq.Queryable`

Comment: also, the type is a generic type, I think you should try to `Call` your expression on an `IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>`,  not a simple `IOrderedQueryable`

Comment: @DavidG oh, ok, my bad then.

Comment: as per my last comment, could you try to use : `typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { TEntity })` instead of `typeof(IOrderedQueryable)` ?

Comment: Note that this will fail at runtime if `TEntity` doesn't have an `Id` property. My preference would be to give all entities with the `Id` property an interface (e.g. `IHasId`) and use a generic constraint here. That way you avoid expressions completely and get compile time safety.

Comment: typeof(IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>) is the same error, typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { TEntity }) gives TEntity is a type which is not valid a this context

Comment: @kosnkov : sorry, I can't try right now myself. Could you then try : `typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { TEntity }).GetType()`

Comment: @kosnkov sorry ! i misread the error . you should use : `typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(TEntity) })`, maybe with `GetType()`at the end as well

Comment: @Pac0 with typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(TEntity) }) the same exception

Comment: I'm out of suggestions right now :/ . I remember trying to call extension methods by reflection, mixed with generics, is slightly tricky...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ThenBy` extension method is in the `System.Linq.Queryable` class, not in `IOrderedQueryable`. You simply need to replace that in your code:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ThenById<TEntity>(
    this IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> source)
{
    //snip

    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(System.Linq.Queryable),
        command,
        new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
        source.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

Note that the method should be extending `IOrderedQueryable`, not just `IQueryable`.

However, this will fail at runtime if `TEntity` doesn't have an `Id` property. My preference would be to give all entities with the `Id` property an interface and use a generic constraint here. That way you avoid expressions completely and get compile time safety. For example:

```
public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntity : IHasId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

Which simplifies your extension method:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ThenById<TEntity>(
    this IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> source)
        where TEntity : IHasId
{
    return source.ThenBy(e => e.Id);
}
```